# Why this .htaccess config cause redirect loop?

Tags: .htaccess

I'm not sure what causes redirect loop here.

```
RewriteEngine on
```

This bit removes .html extention

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

This bit force non www

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

this bit supposed to force SSL, but apparently I get redirect loop when add this, but from what I understand this should only trigger if HTTPS is off?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What is the nature of the redirect loop exactly? What does your `.htaccess` look like as a whole - is it in the order you have posted the directives? (If so, they are in the wrong order.) How is your SSL cert managed? `HTTPS` is not necessarily the correct server variable to use on some shared hosts and/or if you are behind an SSL proxy like Cloudflare etc.? What URL are you requesting? Your rewrite rule that appends the `.html` extension is not necessarily correct (resulting in a rewrite loop), depending on how the requested URL maps to the filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked was:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(.well-known)(/|$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It was webfaction shared hosting, so it looks like server variable ${HTTPS} was not correct as @MrWhite pointed out.